# JS Function Every 100 Points

Tags: unity-game-engine, increment, unityscript, points

I tried writing this on my own, but I failed miserably. Right now I have a script checking the score in my game. I check for every 100 points and change a variable depending on the score, but I'm doing it the wrong and tedious way:

```
if(gameController.speed == 1) {

    if(score >= 200) {
        squishyController.gravity = -25;
    }

    if(score >= 300) {
        squishyController.gravity = -50;
    }

    if(score >= 400) {
        squishyController.gravity = -75;
    }

    if(score >= 500) {
        squishyController.gravity = -100;
        gamePause = true;
        // Spawn First Boss
    }

    if(score >= 600) {
        squishyController.gravity = -125;
    }

    if(score >= 700) {
        squishyController.gravity = -150;
    }
}
```

You get the point. What I want to do in word form is this:

- For every 100 points

  - Change gravity by -25
  - if the points are 500, 1000, etc
  - spawn boss

That's it in a nutshell. Here's what I'm thinking it would look like but don't kill me.

```
for (var i = 0; i += pointValue) {

// Check if points are being added then add to score depending on point value
if(getPoints == true) {
  i++;
}


// For every 100 points change the gravity value
if(i >= incrementsOf100) {
  gravity = gravity -= 25;
}

// For every 500 points, spawn a boss more difficult than the last

if(i = incrementsOf500) {
  bossDifficulty = bossDifficulty += 100; // Just adding this because I will add more hitpoints to boss.
  spawnBoss = true;
}
```

}

Comment: `squishyController.gravity = (Math.floor(score / 100) * -25)`

Comment: Your if checks are bad. You should start with biggest and use else if. Right now large numbers enter into every if.

Comment: Is there a resource you could send me to that explains why I should start with bigger numbers, so I can get a better understanding. Math is my not my strong suit and so I get pretty befuddled when I am working with it.

Comment: adeneo Thanks! I did some more reading about operators and with atmd's answer and yours I got a better understanding of how to do this and got it working. You guys rock!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the modus operator to find the remainder of dividing by 100, then divide the score minus that remainder to get the number of times you need to change gravity

```
var score = 550;
var extra = score % 100;
var gravityTimes = (score - extra) / 100;

gravity = gravity -= (25 * gravityTimes);
```

Comment: Atmd, thanks for breaking down adeneos answer there, I appreciate the thoroughness.

Comment: In reality @adeneo 's answer is the one to implement, but I like to break down the process as a first step then refactor as and when